# Conversion of AppGer.gf and AppFre.gf to .Pgf not working

Tags: gf

when trying to convert `AppGer.gf` and `AppFre.gf` to `.Pgf`, I am getting out of memory error. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Following is the snapshot of the code and error:

```
$ make AppGer.pgf

mkdir -p ./gfos && gf -s -make -literal=PN,Symb -probs=./app.probs -gfo-dir ./gfos -name=AppGer AppGer.gf

gf: out of memory (requested 1048576 bytes)

Makefile:61: recipe for target 'AppGer.pgf' failed

make: *** [AppGer.pgf] Error 251
```

Comment: This question is unclear. What is gf? And what does this have to do with haskell?

Answer (score 1):

GF is [Grammatical Framework](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/), a programming language for writing multilingual grammars. GF is implemented in Haskell, but this question has nothing to do with Haskell.

In case someone else with a similar problem has found this question by googling the error message, the issue has been discussed on GitHub: https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/GF/issues/35. Relevant answers from the issue:

> It works but you need a lot of memory.
>   I have 16GB as well but I can't reproduce the problem. I have seen this problem before. Sometimes French fails to compile but then if I run the make file once more it succeeds. I guess that with the given memory the compiler manages to do part of the compilation and the output is stored in the .gfo files. On the second run it does the rest. I have never had the same problem with German.